# Поиск по карте Google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, search

Существует ли способ с коробки, как говорится, для реализации такого поиска по карте: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или это нужно вручную все прописывать, и рисовать `views`

Comment: Edittext, у которого выставлен drawableRight. Чем не способ из коробки?

Comment: Я имею ввиду сам поиск, а не реализацию edittext, как получить результаты

Comment: вместо EditText я вам рекомендую использовать SearchView.

Comment: ну, реализация с "рисованием views не связана..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что я хотел - `Android Places API`

И подробно описывается как сделать `AutoCompleteTextView` с поиском по карте. 
Кидаю ссылку на ресурс, пользователям будет полезно:
[Autocomlete](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/)